# How can I pull the correct data from the HK Current User registry key instead of temp profile information

Tags: vbscript

I am working on a script to pull the value in the key

```
HKCurrentUser\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Desktop
```

Currently all it is returning is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

When I want/think it should return:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Desktop
```

Below is the script that is pulling the infomration from the key and as far as I can tell it should be pulling the correct information. Just wondering if someone can enlighten me as to what I am missing. It also returns the computer name and the logged in username which both return correctly. This is going to be run on quite a few machines remotely.

```
'These are the constants for the following KEYS'
Const HKClassesRoot = &H80000000 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
Const HKCurrentUser = &H80000001 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Const HKLocalMachine = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Const HKUsers = &H80000003 'HKEY_USERS
Const HKCurrentConfig = &H80000005 'HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG
'Setup objects to interact with here'
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strComputer = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%")
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Define variable to store the current user and then pull the current user
Dim currentUser
strCurrentUser = objNetwork.UserName

'find the data in the string we want to get the value from'
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\"
strValueName = "Desktop"
'pull the info and store it in strValue'
objRegistry.GetStringValue HKCurrentUser,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue

'setup for output of data to the file'
Dim strSpacer
Dim strData
strSpace = "+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+"
strData = "|  " & strComputer & " == " &  strCurrentUser & " == " & strValue & " |"

Dim strFileName
strFileName = "\\server\share\" & strCurrentUser & ".txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName,8,true)
objFile.write vbCrLf & strSpace & vbCrLf
objFile.write strData & vbCrLf
objFile.write strSpace & vbCrLf

'Close file'
objFile.Close
```

After review I found the answer to my own question. I was reading the registry incorrectly for what I was doing.

```
strRegkey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Desktop"
strDataValue = wshShell.RegRead(strRegKey)
```

this returns the value stored currently in the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the environment variable `%USERPROFILE%` from the registry value gets expanded to the profile of the user running the WMI service (LOCAL SYSTEM). `GetStringValue` seems to behave the same as `GetExpandedStringValue` when reading REG_EXPAND_SZ values.